# Spring MVC: Error 400 The request sent was syntactically incorrect

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, controller

In short, I have a Spring 3.1 MVC project and my controller doesn't respond to the POST request when I hit the submit button.

There is no error, just no response. The controller method is not being called. I have a logger in the method that displays an INFO message and nothing is displayed (other INFO messages do display). MVC is working (at least partial) because I get a response from a "home" JSP page, but nothing for a POST.

I'm including things that seem important; tell me if there's something you'd like to see.

Controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/index")

public class Test {
    @Autowired
    private IAdminService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public String lister(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("matieres", service.liserMatiere());


        return "Action";
    }
@RequestMapping(value="/saveMat", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView saveMat(@ModelAttribute("matiere") Matiere m) {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.addObject("mat", m);

            service.ajouterMatiere(m);
            mav.setViewName("Action");

            return mav;
        }
```

and this the NouvelleMat.jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f"%>

    <f:form class="form-horizontal" method="POST"
        action="saveMat" modelAttribute="matiere">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><f:input path="name" maxlength="30" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subject:</td>
                <td><f:input path="subject" maxlength="50" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">Message:</td>
                <td><f:textarea path="note" cols="70" rows="20" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><f:button type="submit" value="Submit matiere" name="submit" /></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </f:form>
```

I got Etat HTTP 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

this is the matiere entity:

```
@Entity
public class Matiere implements Serializable{

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id


        private String name;

        private String subject;


        private String note;

           getters and setters....

}
```

Comment: Please don't open a new question that is identical to your last. Delete this one or the other one. Provide us with the details requested so we can help. Right now, we need you to enable DEBUG level for your logs and show us what is printed.

Comment: Also, show us `Matiere`.

Comment: Still need those logs. Not much we can do without.

Comment: i replace @modelattribute with @requestParam(value="matiere"),Matiere m and i got this Required Matiere parameter 'matiere' is not present

Comment: Please don't do unrelated changes like that. Please just turn your logs to DEBUG and show us what gets printed. (For that particular case, you are not sending a `matiere` request parameter and by default `@RequestParam` annotated parameters are required.)

Comment: i debug but with the old method is not called

Comment: No, the method won't get called. Spring fails to do some parsing and decides to send a 400 response. **But it will log WHY** and I'd like to see it.

Comment: the problem is that dont get any log trace of why

Comment: You say in your question that INFO messages are displayed. Enable DEBUG messages for Spring. If they are not displaying, you are doing it wrong. Use slf4j, log4j, logback, Jakarta, whatever. Just get logs to display. Spring will tell you exactly what it is doing.

Comment: Can `@GeneratedValue` be used for a `String` as ID?  I think if you are using `String` as ID, you have to assign it manually.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i think slashes at the beginning of the method RequestMapping are unnecessary, they will be relative to classe's "/index".

But to debug such problem, You should check out the request your browser sends to the controller.

If You are using Chrome, go with ctrl+shift+c to open the console, or F12 for firebug in Firefox, or console in IE. Go to network, and check out what is Your browser sending. You will probably be able to tell what is the mistake by looking at the request body and headers.